# Access model from shared partial view independent of controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating a simple webpage in asp.net mvc 3.

I have a sidebar that loads random citations, and the sidebar is on every page so it's a part of the layout, independent of the controller.

What is the correct way to access a datamodel from that view? Do I have to pass data from each controller?

My partial view file looks something like:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.CitationModel
@Model.Citation
```

But this results in a null reference.

The model is something like

```
   public class CitationModel
{
    public string Citation{ get { return "Test"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this with a child action. This way you can keep the view strongly typed (no viewbag or viewdata), without having to put it in a "master" viewmodel that gets sent to your layout:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    @Html.Action("RandomCitations", "Citations")
</div>
```

In CitationsController:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult RandomCitations()
{
    var model = new CitationModel();
    // populate model
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Your view will stay the same, and will be injected into the sidebar div for every layout.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up. What is the recommended naming convention here? I've named my other partial pages with a leading _ (underscore).

So I've named my method _RandomCitations() since it returns a partial view. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Don't prefix method names with underscores. Partial view names (cshtml files) are prefixed with an underscore to distinguish that they are partial views by convention. However this convention does not apply to action method names that return a partial view.

Comment: I had the same question and implemented code as u described here. and now the controller method it called multiple times by my partial view

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of scenarios there.
For now for that cases I put model to view bag, and then getting it from viewbag on view.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a base controller class like this:

```
public class ApplicationController : Controller
    {
        public ApplicationController()
        {
           Citation c = getYourCitation();

           ViewBag.Citation = c;
        }
}
```

Get all your controllers to inherit from Application controller

```
public class HomeController : ApplicationController
    {
       //Controller code
    }
```

Each view (including _Layout) will then be able to access the ViewBag

in _Layout.cshtml do this:

```
@Html.Partial("_CitationPartial", (Your.MidTier.Models.Citation)ViewBag.Citation)
```

Comment: If you want to put something in the viewbag for every view, why not do it with a global ActionFilter? Makes construction logic for your base controller not necessary.